# Manually restore installed softwares on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, reset

*I haven't found any information related to this on the internet, so I thought of asking it here.*

Recently, I performed a reset of my Windows 10 PC. Before the reset, I had moved all my important softwares from the **Program files** and **Program files (x86)** folders. After the reset, I restored the softwares to their respective folders.
The softwares are running fine when I double-click on their exe files, but the problem is that those softwares are not listed under **Programs and features** section of **Control panel**. It means that the softwares are somehow not got recognised by the Windows system. See these screenshots: [Control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWcj8.png), [**Program files** folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STDla.png) and [**Program files (x86)** folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLJtH.png).

So, what to do to make Windows recognise those softwares?

Comment: Install the software. Copying files is not the same as installing.

Comment: What @harrymc said, you need to re-install the applications properly.

Comment: To help you eliminate the root cause of the problem in the future, **why** did you move your software out of the `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry entries for all this software is missing from the operating system since you have reset it. You cannot just copy the files over and have them appear in the 'add/remove programs'.

The easiest way, would be just to re-install the software using the installer (or use 'repair' option in the installer/uninstaller if availble).